# How to highlight certain strings in R tablehtml?

Tags: r, highlight, tablehtml

This is what I want

[image: Please click to see the screenshot]

Here is my code following Clemens post

```
library(magrittr)
sample1$sentence %<>% 
stringr::str_replace_all(c('red' = '<span style="background- color:blue">red</span>'))
sample1 %>% 
tableHTML()
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tableHTML)
```

The sample data:

```
sample1 <- data.frame(words = c("interested", "red", "black"),
                      sentence = c("I am very interested in this topic",
                                   "Multiple color: red, blue, black",
                                   "multiple color: red, blue, black"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create a list to store words and the colour you want to apply to them:

```
word_colour <- list(interested = "red",
                    red = "blue",
                    black = "purple")
```

The function below uses the `word_colour`, looks for the word in the sentence and adds a `span` around it with inline `CSS` that changes the font colour.

```
replace_word <- function(word_colour, df) {
  word <- df$words
  sentence <- df$sentence

  stringr::str_replace(string = sentence,
                       pattern = word,
                       replacement = paste0('<span style="color:', 
                                            word_colour[[word]], 
                                            '">',
                                            word,
                                            '</span>'))

  }
```

You can then chain it all together. Important note: `rowwise` allows you to go through the data row by row. `do()` is used as a general purpose manipulation function.

```
sample1 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  do({
    df = as_data_frame(.)
    df$sentence = replace_word(word_colour, df)
    df
  }) %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            escape = FALSE)
```

The result is:

[image: output]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!